# Find roots of $f = e^{2z}-1,$ where $z = x+iy$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots

Calculate the roots of $f = e^{2z}-1$, where $z = x+iy$.

If I use $e^{2z}-1=0$, then I get $2z = \ln(1)$ so $x = iy$, but is this correct?

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: What do you mean "analitically"? Either you know where the exponential function equals one or you don't.

Comment: what is $ln(1)$?

Comment: natural logarithm, $ln(1) = 0$

Comment: That would imply that $y=0$, since $\ln(1)$ is real, so that is not correct.

Comment: so what is correct then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that

$$e^{2z}=e^{2x}e^{2iy}=1\implies e^{2x}=1 \implies x=0.$$

So we have $$e^{2iy}=1\implies 2y=2n\pi, \quad n\in \mathbb{Z}.$$

So $$z=in\pi.$$

Comment: @user394 If there is something in the above that you don't understand (for instance the first line), please do let me know, and I'll elaborate.

Comment: I understand how to solve $e^{2x}=1$ and $e^{2iy}=1$. What I don't understand is how  you deduced those two equations from $e^{2x}e^{2iy}=1$. Is it correct that because 1 is the real part you say $e^{2x}=1$, solve that, you find $x=0$, plug that in $e^{2x}e^{2iy}=1$ and then you get the second line which you eventually solved. So the zeros of $f$ are $in \pi $

Comment: and should $n$ be even as suggested by DonAntonio?

Comment: @user394 That's exactly right! I look at $e^{2iy}$ and see that it is a complex number with length $1$, which multiplied with $e^{2x}$ still has length $1$, so $e^{2x}=1.$ And $n$ can be any integer. I suspect DonAntonio uses $2n=k$.

Comment: No need to suspect, just to read carefully what I wrote **and then** to traduce that to the actual problem in the question.

Comment: @DonAntonio Well okay, then I'm **sure**.

Comment: @Lovsovs thank you both very much !

Answer (score 2):

Observe that (complete detalis)

$$e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)=1\iff\begin{cases}e^x\sin y=0\iff &y=k\pi,\,k\in\Bbb Z\\{}\\
e^x\cos y=1\end{cases}$$

and knowing that **it must be** $\;y=k\pi\;,\;\;k\in\Bbb Z\;$ from the first line above, it follows that

$$e^x\cos k\pi=1\iff x=0,\,\,k\;\,\text{is even}$$

Well, now try to attack your problem *again* taking the above into account.

Answer (score 0):

$\ln$ is a "multi valued" function. In particular, $ln(1)"="\{2\pi i n|n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$. I use $"="$ since the precise interpretation of this statement depends on the context and your definition. But you can think about it as follows:

$$\forall n\in\mathbb{Z}:e^{2\pi i n}=1$$
So if we denote 
$$f:\mathbb{C}\to \mathbb{C}:x\mapsto e^x$$
then $f$ is not injective, and hence does not have a well defined inverse function. However, choosing a pre image, for example $1$, and a "cut", for example the negative $x$-axis, specifies a "branch". This means that this data gives a function
$$ln_{1,(-\infty,0]}:\mathbb{C}\setminus (-\infty,0]\to \mathbb{C}$$
such that
$$e^{ln_{1,(-\infty,0]}(x)}=x$$
However, there are infinitely many functions that satisfy this property, corresponding to different choices of the pre image and cut. There is an arguably more elegant solution to this problem in the realm of complex geometry and anlysis, namely the notion of a Riemann surface, but that's too long a story to tell here.

So, coming back to your question, your mistake is that it is not true that
$$e^z=1\Rightarrow z=0$$

Comment: *your mistake is that it is not true that
$e^x=1\Rightarrow x=0$* - well, $x$ is real, how could $x=0$ *not* be the implication?

Comment: Ah, sorry, my mistake (no need, I just assumed you used the notation of OP)!

Comment: @Lovsovs Ah sorry on my part:p I did not realise this notation might cause confusion for the OP. Thanks